# Taskwarrior Question : Howto show completed projects?

Tags: taskwarrior

to show all completed tasks the command is in Taskwarrior :

task status:completed all

but what is the command for showing only the completed projects

(not including the completed tasks !)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to get a pretty-printed list of all projects you ever used, including the number of tasks per project:

```
task rc.list.all.projects=1 projects
```

If you want a flat list, without the number of tasks, use `_projects`, i.e.

```
task rc.list.all.projects=1 _projects
```

The part `rc.list.all.projects=1` is a command line override for the config value. You could also use the `config` command to set these values in your `.taskrc` if you always want to see all projects:

```
task config list.all.projects 1
```

This can be useful if you often add tasks to completed projects, as it also influences which projects are suggested by autocomplete.

Source: https://taskwarrior.org/docs/examples.html#projects

Comment: hartelijk dank Reinoud !